# Having trouble with remove()

Tags: c++, fstream

I am having some trouble. What I am trying to do is make a file named `<username>.txt` and change a line in that file.  The function should create a new file `<username>.n` where it makes the changes, and then delete the original file and rename the new file to `<username>.txt`.

The problem is that this does not work:

```
remove(user + ".txt");
//and
rename(user + ".n", user + ".txt");
```

It does not work because `remove()` and `rename()` only accept char arrays and not strings. Is there any workaround?

Please don't just say "convert the string to a char array". I tried this, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: "*Please don't just say "convert the string to a char array". I tried this, but I can't get it to work*" - what EXACTLY did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rename(/*oldpath=*/(user + ".n").c_str(),
       /*newpath=*/(user + ".txt").c_str());
```